# Cart Summary info disappearing

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, order-summary

I am having an issue with the cart summary on the checkout page, when you mouse over the info with item name and price are disappear.

[image: Normal summary]
[image: mouse over item]

Has anyone else encountered this, I have been over as much of the code as I can find and cant seem to figure out why its happening or how to stop it. I haven't been able to look into the JavaScript because I don't really know JS well enough to find the code that runs this.

Comment: i think this is theme features

Answer (score 0):

Open the Developer tools in Chrome or Firefox and right click to select inspect element,once you have the target click in `hover` and inspect the CSS properties, maybe the text is the same color that your background.
[image]

Comment: I have done that, and there is an `::after` that disappears and reappears with the text, but the only rule it has is  `content: ": ";`. I cant find any other CSS rules that change in any element